# A different number of features in the SVC.coef_ and samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, data-analysis

I downloaded the data.

```
news = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups.data)
y = news.target
print(X.shape)
```

The shape of X is `(1786, 28382)`

Next I trained the model and got the coef_ shape

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=241, C = 1.0000000000000001e-05)
clf.fit(X, y)
data = clf.coef_[0].data
print(data.shape)
```

The shape is `(27189,)`

Why the number of features are different?

Comment: why do you even do clf.coef_[0].data ? this is supposed to be a **buffer**, not your data. print clf.coef_.shape

Comment: @lejlot Yes, you are right, the shape of coef_ is (1, 28382). But the shape of clf.coef_.data is (27189,) too. How I can get all data?

Comment: coef_ **is** your data. Leave data field alone :-) just take _coef[0][i]

Comment: @lejlot Thanks a lot! I can't iterate over coef_[0], but clf.coef_[0].toarray() works fine)

Comment: you can iterate, but not directly since if data is **sparse** so are coefs, and iterating over sparse arrays in python is a bit non trivial

Comment: @lejlot Sorry can you help me one more) coef_.indices shape is (27189,) too)This topic is advised to use .data and .indicies http://stackoverflow.com/a/10364941/5446420  How I can get indicies? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124100/discussion-between-it-nike-and-lejlot).

Comment: if you want to know how to iterate over sparse array, just ask a separate question, as this is a different problem (and probably already has lots of answers on SO). calling "toarray()" is a good idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in short everything is fine, your weight matrix is in clf.coef_. And it has valid shape, it is a regular numpy array (or scipy sparse array if data is sparse). You can do all needed operations on it, index it etc. What you tried, the .data field is attribute which holds **internal** storage of the array, which can be of different shape (since it might ignore some redundancies etc.),  but the point is you should not use this internal attribute of numpy array for your purpose. It is exposed for low level methods, not for just reading out