# Why does indptr not match the values in this csr matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm having a hard time understanding why this behaviour is happening.

I have a scipy sparse csr matrix. The first ten elements are:

```
print my_mat[0:10,]

  (0, 31)       1
  (0, 33)       1
  (1, 36)       1
  (1, 40)       1
  (2, 47)       1
  (2, 48)       1
  (3, 50)       1
  (3, 53)       1
  (4, 58)       1
  (4, 60)       1
  (5, 66)       1
  (5, 68)       1
  (6, 73)       1
  (6, 75)       1
  (7, 77)       1
  (7, 82)       1
  (8, 30)       1
  (8, 32)       1
  (9, 37)       1
  (9, 40)       1
```

When I call `indptr`, I get:

```
m1 = my_mat[0:10,]
print m1.indptr
[ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20]
```

Why don't the values of `indptr` equal:

0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3, etc (the first column of my_mat, which is what is implied from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360210/access-value-column-index-and-row-ptr-data-from-scipy-csr-sparse-matrix))? How can I access those values?

Comment: That 2012 answer misled you.  `indptr` is a special `csr` condensed array, and not the same as the `row` attribute of the equivalent `coo` format matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSR matrix, `m1.indptr` does not hold the row indices.  Instead, for row `r`, the pair of values `start, end = m1.indptr[r:r+2]` gives the start and end indices into `m1.data` of the values that are stored in row `r`.  That is, `m1.data[start:end]` holds the nonzero values in row `r`.  The columns of these values are in `m1.indices[start:end]`.

In your example, you have `m1.indptr = [ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20]`.  So the nonzero values in the first row are stored in `m1.data[0:2]`, and the columns where these values are located are stored in `m1.indices[0:2]`.  The nonzeros values stored in the second row are `m1.data[2:4]`, and their columns are `m1.indices[2:4]`, etc.

If you want the row and column indices, probably the simplest method is to use the `nonzero()` method.  For example, here is a CSR matrix:

```
In [50]: s
Out[50]: 
<5x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [51]: s.A
Out[51]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 40,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 30,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

Here we use the `nonzero()` method to get the row and column indices of the nonzero values:

```
In [71]: row, col = s.nonzero()

In [72]: row
Out[72]: array([0, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)

In [73]: col
Out[73]: array([1, 2, 5, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Alternatively, you could convert the array to the "COO" (coordinate) format.  Then you can access the `row` and `col` attributes:

```
In [52]: c = s.tocoo()

In [53]: c.row
Out[53]: array([0, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)

In [54]: c.col
Out[54]: array([1, 2, 5, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: `s.nonzero()` does the `tocoo` conversion, plus an additional filter for possible zero values (sparse methods don't always `eliminate_zeros`).